# Error HTTP Status 500 - The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files

Tags: java, maven, jstl, java-ee-7

I am trying to develop simple java web app which displays simple hello world but when i try to add jstl to it's not working!

Here is my Project Structure
[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPREm.png)

Web.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <display-name>My CRUD Application 6</display-name>

</web-app>
```

index.jsp

```html
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h2>Hello World!</h2>

  </body>
</html>
```

And Here is Pom.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>zambroo.crud6</groupId>
    <artifactId>crud6</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

And Here is complete Tomcat Log

```html
18-Dec-2015 23:35:34.062 SEVERE [http-apr-8080-exec-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/crudsix] threw exception [The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application] with root cause
 org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
 at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:55)
 at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:277)
 at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:75)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2503)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2492)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

18-Dec-2015 23:35:34.553 SEVERE [http-apr-8080-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/crudsix] threw exception [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp] with root cause
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:131)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:62)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:129)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:171)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:375)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2503)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2492)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

And The Error page Please Run the Snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/8.0.28 - Error report</title><style type="text/css">H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}.line {height: 1px; background-color: #525D76; border: none;}</style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp</h1><div class="line"></div><p><b>type</b> Exception report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u></p><p><b>exception</b></p><pre>org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:176)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:375)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
</pre><p><b>root cause</b></p><pre>java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
 java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:131)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:62)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:171)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:375)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
</pre><p><b>note</b> <u>The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.28 logs.</u></p><hr class="line"><h3>Apache Tomcat/8.0.28</h3></body></html>
```

When i remove the First line from the index.jsp i.e. the taglib line, everything works fine. I think I have imported all the required depnedencies in the pom.xml.

Please let me know what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Screenshot suggests you're using IntelliJ IDEA. Is this true? If so, that's in turn the cause. Your pom is fine albeit unnecessarily convoluted. The pom in answer is perfectly fine and works at least in Eclipse and Netbeans based projects.

Comment: Kindly have a look at the following answer

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Balus C, You are using IntelliJ Idea.
I am using Intellij Idea 15

The problem is with POM.XML

I changed your POM.XML as

> Added - Packaging Type to WAR

```html
<groupId>zambroo.crud6</groupId>
<artifactId>crud6</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

> Added BUILD Details after Dependencies node ends

```html
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java/unit</testSourceDirectory>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/java/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>web</warSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Now everything works Fine for me!!!!!!

Hope this HELPS you JwB!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is in your pom.  Simply put, the container doesn't think that the JSTL library is there when it is deployed, or there is a conflict.

You're specifically including the JSTL directly, version 1.2.1 and then also including the glassfish implementation of it (so, which do you want?).

You've excluded almost everything that glassfish provides anyway.  There is likely something not working with your exclusions. I would remove the glassfish dependency all together and see if it plays nicer.

You could remove them both and simply try this one:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Tried as you said but, that was of **no use!**

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
-right click on your maven project; 
-go to "maven" and then click on "Update project".

It works for me.